how to draw tilted light cones?
I am having trouble in drawing tilted light cones on the second ellipse and in alignment of circle with its lines to get the slanted light cone. I have edited and updated this post 3 times and really upset that no one is giving me any hint of doing that but posting links to read. Please see my attached picture. Here is "my code"
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \filldraw[black] ellipse (0.5 and 0.25);
        \draw (0,0) ellipse (3 and 0.5);
        \draw (0,0) ellipse (4.5 and 1);
        \draw (0,0) ellipse (6 and 1.5);
        \draw (-6,0)--(-5.5,1);
        \draw (-6,0)--(-6.5,1);
        \draw (-6,1) circle (0.5 cm and 0.1 cm);
        \draw (0,1.5)--(0.5,2.5);
        \draw (0,1.5)--(-0.5,2.5);
        \draw (0,2.5) circle (0.5 cm and 0.1 cm);
        \draw (-4.5,0)--(-5.5,1);
        \draw (-4.5,0)--(-5,1);
        \draw [rotate=10] (-5.25,1) circle (0.5 cm and 0.1 cm)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}



Welcome. // I suggest to spend some time on learning tikz: https://tikz.dev/ . The first one is no big deal, and the second is not that complicated either.

Please don't be disappointed. The start here can be rough, as it's different. Following your edits I saw you moved from "help" via a first drawing to "a very specific question". The latter is a good starting point in this community. So: you made it, and soon you'll become more fluent both in Tikz and in cooperating with this place. Keep on posting good questions :)

Your question matured, so here are some hints for you. Some remarks, where I suggest looking up all Tikz-related statements in the pgfmanual in parallel.
These demos and explanations should help you drawing most parts of your intended drawing.
Let's have a look at the result from my code posted below, first:

You see a lonly cone on top, and a few other drawings below. This is caused by the documentclass I used by intention: standalone. It's nice to create drawings separately. Each tikzpicture environment makes it "eject" a new page with the correct size.
The lonely cone comes from analysing your posted code. I put some comments to better understand what you did. With dedicated commenting out after a few compiles I understood enough. // I highly recommend to start Tikz drawings with putting comments first about what you will do: it's both self-documenting and assisting on the way.
Next, a new tikzpicture starts. At its beginning I defined a \pic, which you can consider being a Tikz way to define "drawnig" macros:
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
        cone/.pic={ % ~~~ defining the \pic ~~~~~~~~
            \draw[fill=white] (-.5,1) -- (0,0) -- (.5,1) -- cycle; 
            \draw[fill=white] (0,1)   circle (0.5 cm and 0.1 cm);   
        },
    ]    

Basically it's a copy of your lonly cone, extended by some fills to overdraw the ellipses later. I did this step by step, and so should you.
The next few lines draw some of these cones with some rotation and a red dotted line to better see their distribution along the x-direction. By intention the \pics reference point is where it is.
    % ~~~ drawing several \pic s ~~~~~~~~~
    \pic                at (0,0) {cone};
    \pic[rotate=-70]    at (2,0) {cone};
    \pic[rotate=-140]   at (4,0) {cone};
    \draw[red,dashed] (0,0) -- (4,0);   % for reference

Next I demonstrated how you can handle the "orbits". It requires a bit more action:

I replaced your ellipse by arc, as you can use option pos to indicate positions along this (elliptic) path
BEFORE the path ends at the ; I put several empty nodes
at different positions pos
giving them names

    % ~~~ how you can handle the "orbits" ~~~~~~~~~
    \draw (0,-4) arc [  % arcs let you put nodes along its path
                      start angle=0,
                      end angle=360,
                      x radius=3cm,
                      y radius=1cm]
            node[pos=.0] (X) {} % one empty node on the orbit
            node[pos=.3] (Y) {} % one empty node on the orbit
            node[pos=.6] (Z) {} % an other one
            ;   % the draw-path ends at this semicolon

What is it good for? Well, NOW you can put cones at those nodes positions (they just were placeholders). (This code part motivated me to introduce fill color in the pics definition.) That's it.
    % ~~~ putting some cones ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \pic              at (X) {cone};
    \pic[rotate=30]   at (Y) {cone};
    \pic[rotate=-100] at (Z) {cone};


\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    % ~~~ your code, with some comments ~~~~~~~~~~
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % ~~~ "orbits" ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%        \filldraw[black] ellipse (0.5 and 0.25);
%        \draw (0,0) ellipse (3 and 0.5);
%        \draw (0,0) ellipse (4.5 and 1);
%        \draw (0,0) ellipse (6 and 1.5);
        % ~~~ one cone ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (-6,0)--(-5.5,1);
        \draw (-6,0)--(-6.5,1);
        \draw (-6,1) circle (0.5 cm and 0.1 cm);
%        \draw (0,1.5)--(0.5,2.5);
%        \draw (0,1.5)--(-0.5,2.5);
%        \draw (0,2.5) circle (0.5 cm and 0.1 cm);
%        \draw (-4.5,0)--(-5.5,1);
%        \draw (-4.5,0)--(-5,1);
%        \draw [rotate=10] (-5.25,1) circle (0.5 cm and 0.1 cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
 
    
 % ~~~ using \pic to draw many cones of the same kind ~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
        cone/.pic={ % ~~~ defining the \pic ~~~~~~~~
            \draw[fill=white] (-.5,1) -- (0,0) -- (.5,1) -- cycle; 
            \draw[fill=white] (0,1)   circle (0.5 cm and 0.1 cm);   
        },
    ]    
    % ~~~ drawing several \pic s ~~~~~~~~~
    \pic                at (0,0) {cone};
    \pic[rotate=-70]    at (2,0) {cone};
    \pic[rotate=-140]   at (4,0) {cone};
    \draw[red,dashed] (0,0) -- (4,0);   % for reference
    
    % ~~~ how you can handle the "orbits" ~~~~~~~~~
    \draw (0,-4) arc [  % arcs let you put nodes along its path
                      start angle=0,
                      end angle=360,
                      x radius=3cm,
                      y radius=1cm]
            node[pos=.0] (X) {} % one empty node on the orbit
            node[pos=.3] (Y) {} % one empty node on the orbit
            node[pos=.6] (Z) {} % an other one
            ;   % the draw-path ends at this semicolon
    
    % ~~~ putting some cones ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \pic              at (X) {cone};
    \pic[rotate=30]   at (Y) {cone};
    \pic[rotate=-100] at (Z) {cone};
    
    % ~~~ labeling the start of the arc ~~~~~~
    \node[anchor=west] at (X) {X, or pos=0};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I understand now. Thank you so much !!
